# Boost Spirit (classic): Inline parser, working except for skipping comments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment on sehe's answer, turns out the code below works just fine; it was my handling of the iterators (not shown here) that was faulty. Sorry, my bad. Voting to close for off-topic / non-reproducable.

**EDIT2:** Elaboration... **if** you're using `boost::spirit::istream_iterator` to feed a `ifstream` to the parse function (like I did), do not forget to call `unsetf( std::ios::skipws )` on that `ifstream` first, or your parsing will fail...

---

I've got a DSL (domain specific language) file that's looking like this:

```
# Comment (optional)

codepage = "ISO-8859-2";
...
```

I.e., either the `codepage` specification is the first non-comment statement in the file, or the file is considered to be of the default codepage.

I commandeered Boost Spirit for the task. I had to stay with Spirit Classic for technical reasons (*cough* AIX / XLC *cough*), and after some head-scratching through the tutorials -- which invariably aim at much more involved setups, being much more complicated than I would like this to be -- I came up with this little piece of code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_rule.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_utility.hpp>

#include <string>

namespace spirit_classic = boost::spirit::classic;

template< typename Iterator >
static std::string getCodepage( Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
    std::string codepage;

    spirit_classic::parse(
        first,
        last,
        spirit_classic::as_lower_d[ "codepage" ]
            >> spirit_classic::ch_p( '=' )
            >> spirit_classic::lexeme_d[ spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' )
                >> ( +( spirit_classic::anychar_p - spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' ) ) )[spirit_classic::assign_a( codepage )]
                >> spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' ) ]
        >> spirit_classic::ch_p( ';' ),
        spirit_classic::space_p | spirit_classic::comment_p( '#' )
        );

    if ( codepage.empty() )
    {
        codepage = "UTF-8";
    }

    return codepage;
}
```

This works pretty well... except for the skipper:

```
...
spirit_classic::space_p | spirit_classic::comment_p( '#' )
...
```

This skips whitespaces allright -- but utterly fails at skipping comments (i.e. anything from `'#'` to end-of-line), which I understood `comment_p('#') to achieve.

So apparently I have understood something wrong. I just cannot figure out what. Help?

Comment: Hrm... I'm surprised that XlC++ still can't handle the spirits. I actually did my first Spirit steps on XlC++ (but yeah, that was probably Spirit Classic). But since then we've seen quite some XlC versions with improvements.

Comment: Anyhoops. I can adequately announce myself a Spirit buff, but not for Classic :( I'm not sure you'll find many to support that old thing (it's even been deleted in 1_66, IIRC)

Comment: @sehe: Somewhat bound to what the company provides me with, and that is XLC v11.1. And boy, did I have "fun" getting Boost to dance on that, because the Boost team doesn't *have* an AIX box to test on. However, I got the impression that there haven't been that many changes in the "simple" layers of the API between Classic and v2. So, does your v2 buff-eye see anything out of place here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much insight here, and I'm only testing with MSVC/GCC here, but perhaps the problem is with `comment_p` trying to consume `eol` (which is eaten by the `space_p` skipper instead)?

So either you could use `spirit_classic::blank_p` (and be explicit about your eols), *or* you might have luck reversing the branches of the skipper:

```
    spirit_classic::comment_p( '#' ) | spirit_classic::space_p
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db792962a19e4504)**:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_rule.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_utility.hpp>

#include <string>

namespace spirit_classic = boost::spirit::classic;

template< typename Iterator >
static std::string getCodepage( Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
    std::string codepage;

    spirit_classic::parse(
        first,
        last,
        spirit_classic::as_lower_d[ "codepage" ]
            >> spirit_classic::ch_p( '=' )
            >> spirit_classic::lexeme_d[ spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' )
                >> ( +( spirit_classic::anychar_p - spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' ) ) )[spirit_classic::assign_a( codepage )]
                >> spirit_classic::ch_p( '"' ) ]
        >> spirit_classic::ch_p( ';' ),
         spirit_classic::comment_p( '#' ) | spirit_classic::space_p
        );

    if ( codepage.empty() )
    {
        codepage = "UTF-8";
    }

    return codepage;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "# Comment (optional)\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "codepage = \"ISO-8859-2\"; \n";

    std::cout << getCodepage(input.begin(), input.end());
}
```

Prints

```
ISO-8859-2
```

Comment: Well, what can I say... turns out my grammar worked all the time, it was my handling of Boost's istream_iterator that was at fault... bummer. Sorry for having wasted your time.